# why wont this form label style

Tags: css, label

For the life of me i cant style these labels as a matter of fact styling some of the elements in a css wont even work. Any help/explaination appreciated

```
<div id="calcbox">
    <form name="form1" class="contact_form">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Item Cost</label>
                <input type="text" id="itemCost" placeholder="$ 0.00" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="button" class="calculatebutton" value="Cash Payment" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="button" class="calculatebutton" value="Card Payment" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label style="width:100px;">Purchase Cost</label>
                <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="$ 0.00" readonly style="clear:both" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What CSS? You haven't posted any.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I guess OP means the inline style for `label`

Comment: Are you talking about the `width`? Label is an `inline` element, not a `block`. Setting an arbitrary width won't work, it will fit its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its about the `width`. However, as long as that's the only CSS in your question,  I'll assume it.

Label is an **inline element**, not a **block**. Setting an arbitrary `width` (as well as some other properties) won't work, it will fit its content.

Still, there's a solution: you can change it's display behavior with `style="width:100px; display: inline-block"`

Comment: but i have seen label been asigned a width multiple tuts..  http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html

Comment: @alex_zander That label is set to `float` too. That's the key here: you can define arbitrary width and height to a floating element.